# Adding New object to existing json file Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json

My json file: DB.json

```
{
"Jobs":[
{
"Name":"Chef",
"StartDate":"1/1/2016",
"EndDate":"5/1/2016",
"Location":"Haifa",
"Description":"Chef in italian restaurant",
"Requirements":"little experience",
"Phone":"050-0000000"
},
{
"Name":"Mailman",
"StartDate":"11/1/2016",
"EndDate":"21/1/2016",
"Location":"Akko",
"Description":"two hours shift as mailman in Haifa area",
"Requirements":"knowledge of the city locations",
"Phone":"050-0000001"
},
{
"Name":"Waiter",
"StartDate":"10/1/2016",
"EndDate":"29/1/2016",
"Location":"Tel Aviv",
"Description":"Double shifts at beach restaurants in haifa",
"Requirements":"couple months of experience",
"Phone":"050-0000002"
},
{
"Name":"Barman",
"StartDate":"15/2/2016",
"EndDate":"22/2/2016",
"Location":"Beer sheva",
"Description":"For morning shifts at good bar in the city center",
"Requirements":"Done it before",
"Phone":"050-0000003"
},
{
"Name":"Dishwasher",
"StartDate":"17/1/2016",
"EndDate":"1/2/2016",
"Location":"Ashdod",
"Description":"Needed for night shifts at most",
"Requirements":"None",
"Phone":"050-0000004"
}
]}
```

My Class for the object adapter:

```
package com.example.rami.jobseeker;


    public class Jobs {
        private String name;
        private String StartD;
        private String EndD;
        private String Location;
        private String Des;
        private String Req;
        private String phone;
```

with setters and getters

I need to add a object the jobs array at the end for now I can read a json file and turn it into string and then put the data into list.
but now I to write into it and no just read it.

Comment: http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/jsonsimple-example-read-and-write-json.html

Comment: You example explains about writing into new file, I want to add to existing json file.